# ActionScript 3.0, Flash CS5, DocumentClass & Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader

I'm googling for a while now and couldn't come up with a solution yet.

What's the proper way to create a preloader with assets in a ActionScript 3.0 flash that uses a Document class and shall contain everything in a single swf?

I want my preloader to be a single graphic with a loading bar. The graphic i have in the library and exporting to actionscript. There are many different assets and classes, all set in the library to export for actionscript.

The problem seems to be that EVERYTHING is exported to frame 1 independantly of what i set in the asset properties.

What happens now if i run it is that i see a white screen until everything is loaded and then it jumps right to the start of my game. the preloader isn't even shown.

So how can I export only the data for the preloader to frame 1, then display my preloader and load all the rest of the swf after this?

I'm looking for a solution that works with a single SWF and with a preloader that contains an image

I'm working with Flash CS5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael's blog has a good (very basic) game tutorial on it. Part 8 is about adding a preloader. One of the better tutorials out there.

http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/

In short. Stick everything on frame 3 in a container so it doesn't load on frame one. (and of course tell them not to load on frame 1)